# python: what is the fastest way to sort a sublist of key from an ordered list

Tags: python

I have a question about speed in sorting an unordered sublist of keys from a long list of keys. So

```
keys =['a','c','b','f','e','d','p','t','s','y','h']
sub_list = ['y','b','a','p']
```

I have two ideas:

```
sublist = sorted(sub_list, key=keys)
```

or,

```
sublist = [key for key in keys if key in sub_list]
```

There might be better ways than these two for all I know. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the result (`sublist`) supposed to be?

Comment: To clarify for others (because it took me a while to get what you're asking): You want to sort a list as quickly as possible, which happens to be a sub-list of another list, which is already sorted.

Comment: Consider using the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to see what is faster than what. (Insert usual pythonic stuff about being lazy and not preoptimizing.)

Comment: I take it that `sorted(sub_list, key=keys)` is meant to be `sorted(sub_list, key=keys.index)` ?

Comment: For future use, you should compare the fastest method you find to the slowest method.  Then multiply the time difference by the number of times you're going to execute that function, to determine how much execution time you've saved.  Finally, compare that with the amount of time you spent optimizing.  The odds are pretty good you'll learn an important lesson it took me embarrassingly long to pick up.

Comment: cameron is correct. Thanks everyone for putting up with the omitted '.index' at the end of the 'sorted' statement I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `sub_list.sort` over sorted because `.sort` makes an inplace sort where `sorted` makes a copy of the sublist prior to sorting

the list comprehension you have made is very slow because the last if statement has to scan trough the entire sub_list (thus do n operations extra per key)

```
sublist = [key for key in keys if key in sub_list]
```

a much faster list comprehension would be this

```
sub_set = set(sublist)
sub_list = [key for key in keys if key in sub_set]
```

because hash and set look ups are O(1) where list lookups are O(n)

sorting is generally O(nlog(n))
and list comprehension are O(n)

however assuming that by:

```
sublist = sorted(sub_list, key=keys)
```

you mean:

```
sublist = sorted(sub_list, key=keys.index)
```

you have list lookups instead of hash looks up and your sorting thus goes from O(nlog(n)) to O((n**2)*log(n))

to get the sorting back to nlog(n) you have to convert your key list to a hash as follows:

```
keys = dict(zip(keys, range(len(keys))))
sublist = sorted(sub_list, key=keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just timeit:

```
In [3]: %timeit sorted(sub_list, lambda a,b: cmp(keys.index(a), keys.index(b)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.22 us per loop

In [4]: %timeit sublist = [key for key in keys if key in sub_list]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 us per loop
```

*EDIT (more methods)*:

```
%timeit sorted(sub_list, key=keys.index)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.8 us per loop
```

This example uses the macros (or whatever they are called in `ipython`) but you can use `timeit` yourself by:

```
import timeit

p = """
keys =['a','c','b','f','e','d','p','t','s','y','h']
sub_list = ['y','b','a','p']"""

s = "sorted(sub_list, lambda a,b: cmp(keys.index(a), keys.index(b)))"

timeit.Timer(stmt=s, setup=p).timeit()
>>> 8.40028386496742

s = "[key for key in keys if key in sub_list]"
timeit.Timer(stmt=s, setup=p).timeit()
>>> 1.9661344551401498
```

So you can just try all the methods you can think of and choose the fastest

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `sub_list.sort()`? It may not be the fastest, but it's certainly easy to understand.